# How to use a find_by_sql query for an ActiveAdmin index page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm using active admin on a project.  I have a request to create a new resource and was given a complex SQL query to use - which connects to a different DB.  All is good - however, I'm somewhat new to ActiveAdmin and curious how to get the index page to use my custom query vs. the default resource.

I just need a nudge/sample to see how to override this default activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare scopes and filters when registering your model with ActiveAdmin.

`app/model/your_model.rb`

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :my_scope, where('some custom SQL')
  scope :my_other_scope, where('some other custom SQL')
end
```

`app/admin/your_models.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.register YourModel do
  scope :my_scope, default: true
  scope :my_other_scope
end
```