# Rails Where Clause PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: subquery must return only one column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I want to take advantage of rails scoping with a custom sql query.  You can click this post for I'm trying to do - especially in ActiveAdmin.

[How to use a find_by_sql query for an ActiveAdmin index page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403436/how-to-use-a-find-by-sql-query-for-an-activeadmin-index-page)

Basically I'm trying to do something like this

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :my_scope, where('some custom SQL')
  scope :my_other_scope, where('some other custom SQL')
end
```

This is my query I tried out first in `Rails C`

```
LesleyGrade.where('select distinct STC_TERM_GPA,
    TERM,
    last,
    first
    from lesley_grades
order by first, term ASC')
```

Essentially it's a subquery in a where clause.  I only want to return a distinct STC_TERM_GPA for per person per row.

These are my attributes in a `lesley_grades` table, which might help in understand the information I'm trying to retrieve.

```
id
user_id
lesley_id
last
first
active
site
cohort
section
sections_title
faculty
completed_term_cred
term
sec_start_date
sec_end_date
grade
stc_cred
active_program
most_recent_program
intent_filed
stc_term_gpa
sta_cum_gpa
start_term
prog_status
last_change_date
created_at
updated_at
```

So I wanted to see if this would work in `Rails C` first and this is what I got.

```
  LesleyGrade Load (51.1ms)  SELECT "lesley_grades".* FROM "lesley_grades"  WHERE (select distinct STC_TERM_GPA,
    TERM,
    last,
    first
    from lesley_grades
order by first, term ASC)
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  subquery must return only one column
LINE 1: ...ECT "lesley_grades".* FROM "lesley_grades"  WHERE (select di...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "lesley_grades".* FROM "lesley_grades"  WHERE (select distinct STC_TERM_GPA,
    TERM,
    last,
    first
    from lesley_grades
order by first, term ASC)
=> #<LesleyGrade::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x3fcb44d60944>
```

I'm not sure how to fix

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  subquery must return only one column
```

Comment: You don't need the `where`.  Also, why are you selecting four columns if you only want one?

Comment: I'm using rails scopes and it looks likes I can pass a where clause (look at the SO post linked - but if not I"ll update it in my post). And I want those four columns because the UI calls for it.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to acheive, but something like this should at least resolve the postgres error you're seeing:

```
LesleyGrade.where('STC_TERM_GPA IN 
    (SELECT STC_TERM_GPA FROM 
        (SELECT DISTINCT STC_TERM_GPA, TERM, last, first
        FROM lesley_grades
        order by first, term ASC) AS results
    )'
)
```

There's a few levels there:

The deepest level says "get me all rows which have a distinct / unique combination of the columns *STC_TERM_GPA, TERM, last, and first*

The next layer says "Of those results, get rid of the other columns and just give me the *STC_TERM_GPA* column.

The outer-most layer says "Give me all rows where the *STC_TERM_GPA* value is in the set of *STC_TERM_GPA* we just selected.

EDIT: it sounds like you don't what a `WHERE` clause at all. You want something like:

```
LesleyGrade.select('STC_TERM_GPA, TERM, last, first').group('STC_TERM_GPA').order('first, term ASC')
```

That's untested. But to select multiple columns, but restrict to distinct values of one column, you'll want to use SQL's `GROUP BY` clause, which is available in Rails' `ActiveRecord` through the `group` method.

BTW, `select distinct STC_TERM_GPA, TERM, last, first from lesley_grades order by first, term ASC` will give you results which are unique on the COMBINATION of `STC_TERM_GPA, TERM, last, first`, not on JUST `STC_TERM_GPA`. I've assumed that while you want all those columns, you only want DISTINCT on the `STC_TERM_GPA`.

Comment: thanks for the help - it's strange cause I'm only suppose to get back 437 rows back when I use the this query `select distinct STC_TERM_GPA,
    TERM,
    last,
    first
    from lesley_grades
order by first, term ASC`  which is what I want.  However when I use your query I'm getting back all results - which is 1440.  I only want the distinct 437 records where each user will have a distinct TERM_GPA.

Comment: You are correct about "wanting DISTINCT on the STC_TERM_GPA." however, there are cases in which the GPA per user per term might be the same.   I ended up doing something like this `LesleyGrade.select('STC_TERM_GPA, max(TERM), max(last), max(first)').group('STC_TERM_GPA').order('max(first), max(term) ASC')` because I got this error  `PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "lesley_grades.term" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT STC_TERM_GPA, TERM, last, first FROM "lesley_grades" not sure if that really fixes the issue - apologies, my sql is terrible